# Javascript length value neither consistent or correct for textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

** Update **

Modified the code for Ricardo Lohmann's suggestion with the additional modification of using val() instead of text().

It is still not correct, but is a whole lot more consistent.  Initially, it is off by 1 character, and is progressively off by an additional 1 character for every enter key pressed in the text area.  I'm not sure yet whether the text area is returning for it yet, but it is not a CRLF.

I think that is the main problem.  I will do some testing on carriage returns and line feeds being passed to the SMS processor, and hope that I can convert it after the fact.

Parsing through the textarea value and adding 1 character to the count for every "enter key" pressed will get the value I am after.

If anyone has ideas on how to get the textarea to use a full CRLF, I'm all ears.

---

I'm allowing managers to create SMS messages and need to show them how many characters are in use.  So far the number of characters is off by 1 when I start and then becomes wildly inaccurate over time.

```
<textarea id="message_content"></textarea>
<div id="message_length"></div>
```

The message content is initially set with Javascript.

```
uri_decoded = 'Test Message\r\nTest Message';
```

Selecting all the text with select-all and throwing into a text editor like Notepad++ shows 26 characters, which is correct. 22 for characters, 2 for white space, and 2 for the CRLF.

The following code shows 25 characters initially, and then just fails to represent it accurately at all:

```
    // Dynamically update the SMS length when keys are pressed
    $("#message_content").keypress(function(e){
      var string_length = $("#message_content").text().length + 1;
      var message_count = string_length / 160;
      message_count = Math.ceil(message_count);  
      var html = '';
      html = html + message_count + ' message(s) - ' + string_length + ' characters';
      $("#message_length").html(html);

    });

    // Dynamically update the SMS length when the textarea blurs
    $("#message_content").blur(function(){
      var string_length = $("#message_content").text().length;
      var message_count = string_length / 160;
      message_count = Math.ceil(message_count);  
      var html = '';
      html = html + message_count + ' message(s) - ' + string_length + ' characters';
      $("#message_length").html(html);
    });

    // Perform an initial update on the character count
    $("#message_content").blur();
```

Now on the keypress function I have added 1 to the length since AFAICT the event does not have access to the content with the new character added.  In any case, the event does not fire initially, and I am evaluating the blur event primarily.

I chose textarea because it accurately represents the CRLF being passed from the database, that is ultimately passed to the SMS processor.

Any help or observations are appreciated in obtaining accurate values.

Comment: why are you using .text() and not .val()?

Comment: I had not considered val().  Is there any particular reason why it would be returning the correct data?

Comment: Uhh I always use .val() for getting the value of (most) input elements. Just as if you used normal javascript - you would use document.getElementById("textarea1").value, not .innerHTML or innerText. Just look at the jQuery API docs for .val() and it explicitly says to use for getting textarea values

Comment: Now that I look at the API docs more, there's even a little explanation about the problem with CR/LF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the following problems:
`var string_length = $("#message_content").text().length + 1;`
return 1 if there's no text [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zVx8s/10/).

Use `keyup` instead.

You can use the same come on both events.

```
$("#message_content").on('blur keyup', function(){
    var string_length = $("#message_content").text().length;
    var message_count = string_length / 160;
    message_count = Math.ceil(message_count);  
    var html = '';
    html = html + message_count + ' message(s) - ' + string_length + ' characters';
    $("#message_length").html(html);
});
```

Comment: Had to modify it from text() to val() as iangpgall suggested.  Still does not get correct character count, but it is more consistent and closer.

Comment: I also don't understand the need for the + 1 to the string value if it is accessing data after the change.  The initial count should match the real value.  I think it may be related to the CRLF

Comment: I'm marking it as answered, but my problem remains with the way CRLF's are counted.  It's clearly not a CRLF and I need to treat each "enter key" pressed as two characters instead of one.  Thanks for the help though. Learning how to bind multiple events in one call is quite useful.